# mysql find records against multiple row condition

Tags: mysql

So here I have multiple table and joined them but here I have put simple example like:
[image]

here i am able to find all those items who has category_id 1 and 3 any one using in query, but now i need and condition here like where category 1 and 3 both matches.

here i need all those items who has category_id 1 and 3 both.

So how to do that?

mysql in query is matching anyone exist, so is there any other function which matches multiple values?

Answer (score 0):

Using INNER JOIN with a subquery to get the items that have both category_id 1 and 3. The subquery would select all the item_id's that have category_id 1 or 3 and the main query would join with the subquery on the item_id.

```
SELECT p1.item_id, p1.product_id, p1.category_id
FROM PRODUCT p1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT item_id
  FROM PRODUCT
  WHERE category_id IN (1, 3)
  GROUP BY item_id
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT category_id) = 2
) p2 ON p1.item_id = p2.item_id
WHERE p1.category_id IN (1, 3);
```

Sample:

```
-- create
CREATE TABLE PRODUCT (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  item_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  product_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  category_id INTEGER NOT NULL
);

-- insert
INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES (3862, 297,0, 1);
INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES (3861, 297,0, 3);
INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES (3860, 23, 0,1);
```

Output:

```
item_id product_id  category_id
297 0   3
297 0   1
```